# Initializing nested structs in C - best practise

Tags: c

I have the following two structs:

```
typedef struct foo__
{
   double *cliendata;
   size_t len;
   size_t f1;
   size_t f2;
}Foo;

typedef struct foobar__
   Foo  a, b, c;
   char[SOME_DIM] name;
   size_t fb1;
   size_t fb2;
   char[SOME_DIM] address;
   Foo d;
   unsigned char id;
}FooBar;
```

I prefer to use EMPTY_FOOBAR2 because I think it is more "correct" (since it initializes all field members, plus, (I think) it aids code readability, as it makes it clear that struct Foobar nests struct Foo as well as some strings.

```
#define  EMPTY_FOO { NULL, 0, 0, 0}
#define  EMPTY_STRING  {""}
#define  EMPTY_FOOBAR1 { {0},{0},{0}, {""}, 0, 0, {""}, {0}, 0}

#define  EMPTY_FOOBAR2 { EMPTY_FOO, EMPTY_FOO, EMPTY_FOO, \
                         EMPTY_STRING, 0, 0, EMPTY_STRING,\
                         EMPTY_FOO, 0}
```

Probably just syntactic sugar, but which is considered "best practise"?

Comment: Your second `struct` is impossible; a struct can't contain an instance of itself. Did you intend another `FOO`, or a pointer?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Well spotted. I'll correct that typo.

Comment: your code is still not really C, the `[]` are in the wrong place

Answer (score 4):

Just use the "universal zero initializer": `<type> <identifier> = {0};`

```
int i = {0};
double x = {0};
char *pname = {0};
char name[100] = {0};
struct tm moment = {0};
struct foo__ one = {0};
struct foobar__ two = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

If initializing with zeros is OK for you, then C's default `= { 0 };` initialization is OK.

If you want something more complicated, I suggest not initializing, but setting in code.
Just write a function that sets what you want, and call it. It will be more simple, readable and reliable that anything you can do with initialization.

Your macros, try as you may to make them nice, seem like bad practice to me.